# JavaFX PasswordField echo char different on Different computer

Tags: javafx

I try to run `javafx` Password Field Demo on my desktop

[image]

enviroment:

```
win7 64   cmd->chcp:GBK
java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

jdk version switch to "`1.8.0_191`" and "`1.8.0_131`",the same result.

then I tried to run the Demo on my colleague's desktop

```
win7 64   cmd->chcp:UTF-8
java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

[image]

But on my notebook

```
win8 64   cmd->chcp:GBK
java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"/"1.8.0_161"/"1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

It shows normally with `BULLET`

Answer (score 0):

The very first line in your version prints the problem is clear:
`cmd->chcp:GBK` vs `cmd->chcp:UTF-8`

On your Notebook and Desktop PC you have the [GBK character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding)) (`cmd->chcp:GBK`) but your collegue's PC uses [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (`cmd->chcp:UTF-8`). As your code therefore also is likely written with the GBK encoding, your colleague's PC tries to interpret the character in UTF-8 but the UTF-8 character space doensn't hold the bullet symbol (if any character at all) there.

I'd suggest you to convert your code to Unicode and use `\u2022` (which is the unicode encoding for the bullet) as the symbol rather than add it typing it or setting it hardcoded in any other way.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I'm still confused why "char BULLET = '\u25cf' " couldn’t be displayed on my UI demo after I try to convert my code to UTF-8,GBK.