# Javafx passwordfield echo displays garbled characters instead of bullet

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

The echo of passwordfield is displayed properly in the scene builder.

[image]

[image]

I also tried using netBeans, and the result is the same.

This is coding environment :

```
Jdk: 1.8.0.191
intelliJ:2019.1
netBeans: 8.0
```

**Main.java** :

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root)); 
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**test.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <PasswordField layoutX="237.0" layoutY="179.0" promptText="password" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

hope it show default echo.

Comment: I also tried to set the file coding in utf-8,but it didnt work.

Comment: Maybe a duplicated question [Encode String to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8)

Comment: I would try the textfield if i cant fix this garbled bug.sorry I am a newcomer didnt know how to edit the problem to make it better even i know what i actually want to ask.Besides,i m bad at English.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like to an encoding problem (have a look on the workspace encoding maybe). At least this is not the only problem you get, it seems you use the JavaFX 11 with scenebuilder (like the namespace suggests is : `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"` with a Java 8 program from what you said, you should harmonize the versions (8 for both or 11 for both).

Comment: This can solve your issue: [JavaFX PasswordField echo char different on Different computer
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368664/javafx-passwordfield-echo-char-different-on-different-computer)

Comment: i already saw it before,but still not work. maybe i should change to use swing.

Comment: Did you bother running `chcp` from the command line? If you read the previous question, why would you leave that info out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get the solution！！！！！！
Just make sure to write the code under jdk11, and it has little to do with file encoding.
setup jdk11 and setup a JavaFX Project for JDK 11 Using Intellij.

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQ6Z.png)

[no bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdX8X.png)